# nginx http to https cause too many redirect

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, https, ssl-certificate

The following nginx setup is working fine for https://DNSNAME and http://DNSNAME

```
upstream prod {
    server server_ip_1;
    server server_ip_2;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass        https://prod;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    }
}
```

But i need to always have the domain setup as https:// and have DNSname init. so when i try to redirect like below. it is causing too many redirect and fails to load the page. Anyone please help on this to fix it.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name DNSName;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you solve this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I split the 80 and 443 into two separate services, something like.

```
upstream prod {
    server server_ip_1;
    server server_ip_2;
}

server {
    listen    80;
    server_name  localhost;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass        https://prod;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    }
}
```

It works for me. Thanks!